# How to send an image as email attachment from application?

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to create an app that will take a picture and then attach that picture to an email and send the email.
what i m trying to say
step 
 1. add recipient Email Address.
 2. add Subject. 
 3. add Some Text.
and Last And Main
 4. Attach image from camera and sent that Mail.

I want to send mail from my own application only?? without using any inbuilt Gmail app?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("application/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From My App"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Myimage.jpeg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

**UPDATE**

Try this [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/), it will help you

Comment: i don't wan't to go on Gmail App and send the mail. I want to send mail using android app that i created not through gmail app.

Comment: you want to send mail from your own application only?? without using any inbuilt app?

Comment: Right, I think Java Mail Api is used for it but i have no idea about that.

Comment: try the link it will definitely help you

Comment: i have never worked on it but it can work you can try this link as well http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Comment: its working but how to attach image file and send the mail please tell if you have any idea.

Comment: please check the link i provided in the comments, it will help you